# Cannot subscript a value of type Results<Object>

Tags: swift2, realm

I've got a Swift property that simply returns a collection of objects from Realm.

```
var categories: Results<Category> {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    return realm.objects(Category).sorted("name")
}
```

However when trying to access the objects via subscript, I get an error:

```
self.categories[0]
```

If I access it directly, it works fine:

```
realm.objects(Category).sorted("name")[0]
```

The error is:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type 'Results<Category>'
```

Comment: do you thing, it is swift2 related? i don't think so. your code is perfectly legal ... so it should have something with Result collection. if you find the devil which is responsible for it, let me know. i have Realm in my 'TO USE' list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug with both my code and the way Xcode is handling the error.

I was trying to set a String property to a Realm Object instance, but it was giving an incorrect error.

```
cell.textLabel.text = self.categories[0]
```

Changing the code to the following remove the error:

```
cell.textLabel.text = self.categories[0].name
```

or this (which allowed me to get the actual error):

```
let object = self.categories[0]
cell.textLabel.text = object.name
```